# Representation of the dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm familiar with the multiplication table of finite groups (used extensively in physics, and may be in mathematics as well). For example, the dihedral group $\mathbb{D}_3$.

Given a representation of $\mathbb{D}_3$, it is trivial to verify whether it satisfies the multiplication table. My question is, whether there is a rule to construct matrix representations (of dimension $>1$) of $\mathbb{D}_3$, starting from its multiplication table. For example, a two-dimensional or three-dimensional matrix representation of $\mathbb{D}_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little insight in the geometrical meaning of the dihedral group will permit you to replace the symbols in the multiplication table by matrices. If you start with the two generators $r$ and $s$ (the 120* rotation and the flip that switches $X-$ and $Y-$ axis respectively) you can use the matrices $r = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi/3) & -\sin(2\pi/3) \\ \sin(2\pi/3) & \cos(2\pi/3) \end{pmatrix}$ and  $s = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. And verify that they satisfy the rules of the multiplication table.